# Logic error with global pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, logic

I discovered how to solve my problem but I don't know how or why it works. I would greatly appreciate someone to take a look at this:

I'm creating a Linked List with a global pointer to point to the head of the list. I created a dummy node in the main thread. What I want to happen is to be able to call the printList() and if there are no nodes other than the dummy node then to print "Person:0" (saying basically the list is empty).

[edit -> Here's my succinct question: Why does the printList() recognize the Person *head = NULL in main() and not the global pointer when it uses it to set the current pointer equal to head?]

With this code I get the following output

```
int main(){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 

    //Person *head = NULL; 
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);

    head = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);
    head->name[0] = '\0'; 
    head->next = NULL;
    head->previous = NULL;
```

Output:

```
main head:0000000000000000 

main head:00000000003F1390 
Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions: print

printList head:00000000003F1390 Person:1 Total People:1
Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions:
```

With the Person*head declared and initialized to NULL in the main() I get the desired result. ***Why does this happen? How come I can't initialize the global pointer and get the same desired result?***

```
int main(){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 

    Person *head = NULL; 
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);

    head = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);
    head->name[0] = '\0'; 
    head->next = NULL;
    head->previous = NULL;
```

Following output:

```
main head:0000000000000000 

main head:00000000005E1390 
Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions: print

printList head:0000000000000000 Total People:0
Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions:
```

Here is the entire program for reference:

```
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

typedef struct S_PersonInLine{
    char name[16];

    struct S_PersonInLine *next;
    struct S_PersonInLine *previous;
}Person;

//pointer to head of the list
//This isn't a global head pointer(wrong). It doesn't go into main (wrong). False it does go into main but it doesn't give the intended result from the printList
Person *head = NULL; //this allows the functions to access the head pointer

//prototypes 
Person *makePerson();
void *addPerson();
void *insert();
void *delete();
void printList();
void cleanUp();


int main(){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); //Figure out what this thing does again and why its necessary
    Person *head = NULL; 
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);

    head = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);
    head->name[0] = '\0'; 
    head->next = NULL;
    head->previous = NULL;

    char input[16];
    char command[16];

    printf("Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions: ");
    while( fgets(input , 15 , stdin) ){ 
    sscanf(input, "%s", command);
        if ( strcmp(command, "quit") == 0 ){
            printf("\n\nBreaking....");
            break;
        } else if ( strcmp(command, "print") == 0 ){
            printList();
        }

    printf("Enter add, insert or delete for Person functions: ");
    }


    return 0;
}

void printList(){
    Person *current = head;
    printf("\nprintList head:%p ", head);
    int count = 0;


    while(current != NULL){
        count++;
        printf("Person:%d %s", count, current->name);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Total People:%d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: You realize your `Person *head;` in `main()` *hides* the global (which remains NULL) while in `main()`, right ? If you want `head` as global, stop declaring one in `main()`. Is there some reason you're not just passing `head` as a parameter rather than juggling a global ? And why the dummy node? `NULL` is a damn-fine indicator of "this list is empty".

Comment: this line: 'setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);' sets the output buffering for stdout to be 'non existant', so anything output via printf, etc is immediately output to the terminal rather than waiting for either program exit or output of a '\n' or a fflush(stdout); or a read from stdin

Comment: always check the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful.  In C, don't cast the returned value from malloc.  It is a void * so will work with any receiving variable

Comment: this line: 'while( fgets(input , 15 , stdin) ){ ' fgets properly handles the receiving buffer (no overflow and allows room for the terminating NUL byte) so the line should be: 'while( fgets(input , sizeof(input) , stdin) ){ '

Comment: @WhozCraig if I don't declare one in main() then printList() doesn't work correctly. I guess I could pass head as a parameter I haven't thought of doing it that way yet. This was my first thought because it seemed simpler.  The dummy node is a safety so that I don't change the head pointer somewhere along in the program.

Comment: @Sankofa If you don't declare one in `main()` and rethink the unnecessary idea of a dummy node, `printList` will certainly work correctly  (as will everything else that expects `head == NULL` to mean the list is empty). Some people prefer they lists house pointers with dummy nodes. My preference is not. ymmv.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right but that doesn't answer why this happens. I know how to do it a different way but I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work. @Whozcraig

Comment: Why *what* happens? They're two different pointers. Anything done to the local `head` in `main()` will not modify the global. Removing that local in `main` and priming global `head` with a dummy node means all your code expecting `head` pointing to NULL means an empty list will have to change. You can't have it both ways (a dummy non-NULL head pointer and functions that expect `head` as `NULL` mens an empty list). You *could* do `Person *current = head ? head->next : NULL;` and keep your current list print code, but *yuck*.

Comment: @whozcraig not being able to have it both ways makes since. I just wasn't sure if I change the printList function to be while(current->next) would give me problems. Thank you.

Comment: @whozcraig yeah that ternary shows that maybe doing it this way isn't making things simpler.

Comment: Why does the printList() recognize the Person *head = NULL in main() and not the global variable? I'm just trying to understand this question.

Comment: @Sankofa it doesn't. `printList` utilizes the global `head` variable **only**. The global `head` is already NULL on inception and with the local-decl of **another** `head` pointer in `main()`, `head` in that context (main) is *not the same pointer variable*. Don't confuse a pointer with what it holds. A pointer is a variable that *holds* an address. Changing the `head` in `main()` simply changes the address in that *local* variable; it has nothing to do with the global variable `head`. I honestly  cannot explain it any better than that.

Answer (score 2):

No state is passed into the `printList` function therefore the variable `head` there refers the the global instance. The reason it is not working for you is because your `main` function is not using the global instance. When you type `Person *head = NULL;` in the `main` function it declares a local variable (i.e., you are not modifying the global instance). Instead you should initialize the global instance by simply typing `head = NULL;`.

Comment: Note: In `main()`,  `head = NULL`, ... not needed as it already is done on the global initializer (which is *also not needed*, as variables with static storage are zero/null initialized per the C standard).

Comment: @WhozCraig I saw that and agree that it's not necessary. I was just trying to explain how it could be set to `NULL` in the main function correctly (i.e., without creating a local variable that shadows the global one).

Comment: I see how Person *head = NULL shadows the global variable thanks. But this doesn't solve the error of printing a empty list. @jamesAdkison. I would like it print a empty list and I know it can be done with a "dummy node" to. I just created a similar program with race cars and it worked...

Comment: @Sankofa then lose the declaration in `main` and start your `printList` from `current = head->next` rather than `current = head`. But you had better already have primed the global `head` in `main` or the deref will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

suggest removing the following lines (completely) from main()
as they
    1) mask the global variable 'head'
    2) put the first entry into the linked list
       which is why the counts, etc 
       when nothing has been specifically inserted into the linked list

```
Person *head = NULL; 
printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);

head = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
printf("\nmain head:%p \n", head);
head->name[0] = '\0'; 
head->next = NULL;
head->previous = NULL;
```

Note: in the print function, check that the contents of 'head'
and not NULL before going into any loop referencing some offset
from 'head' as with out that check, the code would be trying
to dereference off memory address 0, leading to 
undefined behaviour and can/will result in a seg fault event